# bat file is running "if" check before getting input parameter

Tags: batch-file, windows-7-x64

Put this in a file called "mybat.bat"
(put it in c:\temp\
do NOT put it in c:\windows)

```
set __rightFolder=.


del "%__rightFolder%\system.ini.copy"


If NOT exist "%__rightFolder%\system.ini.copy" (
    copy "%windir%\system.ini" "%__rightFolder%\system.ini.copy"
    ECHO "%__rightFolder%\system.ini.copy"
    SET /P AREYOUSURE="Do you want to run the dir command on '%__rightFolder%\system.ini.copy'"
    IF /I "%AREYOUSURE%" EQU "Y" (
        dir "%__rightFolder%\system.ini.copy"
    )
)


PAUSE
```

When I run this simple script, the "IF /I" is running before I type anything in.
NOTE, I have a long question with quotes around the question.

It's probably something simple, but I'm .bat skillzz stink.

Here is my output.

```
C:\Temp>set __rightFolder=.

C:\Temp>del ".\system.ini.copy"
Could Not Find C:\Temp\system.ini.copy

C:\Temp>If NOT exist ".\system.ini.copy" (
copy "C:\Windows\system.ini" ".\system.ini.copy"
 ECHO ".\system.ini.copy"
 SET /P AREYOUSURE="Do you want to run the dir command on '.\system.ini.copy'"
 IF /I "" EQU "Y" (dir ".\system.ini.copy" )
)
        1 file(s) copied.
".\system.ini.copy"
Do you want to run the dir command on '".\system.ini.copy"'y

C:\Temp>PAUSE
Press any key to continue . . .
```

So I put in 'y', but it doesn't do the "dir" command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neverending story... [EnableDelayedExpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)

> Delayed Expansion will cause variables to be expanded at execution
>   time rather than at parse time, this option is turned on with the
>   `SETLOCAL` command. When delayed expansion is in effect variables may
>   be referenced using `!variable_name!` (in addition to the normal
>   `%variable_name%` )

Patched:

```
set __rightFolder=.
del "%__rightFolder%\system.ini.copy"
If NOT exist "%__rightFolder%\system.ini.copy" (
    copy "%windir%\system.ini" "%__rightFolder%\system.ini.copy"
    ECHO "%__rightFolder%\system.ini.copy"
    SET /P "AREYOUSURE=Do you want to run the dir command on '%__rightFolder%\system.ini.copy' "
    SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
    IF /I "!AREYOUSURE!" EQU "Y" (
        dir "%__rightFolder%\system.ini.copy"
    )
    ENDLOCAL
)
PAUSE
```

Comment: Thanks.  This saved the day (tomorrow) .  I'm definitely not "bat"man.  Pa duh dump.  (I'm here all week folks).